# How to give equal space between the items using tailwind css v3

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am using Tailwind CSS with next.js.
I have 8 images of different sizes and want to keep 4 images in a row for mid and large-size devices and 2 images in a row for small-size devices.

I want to give equal space between the items in a row but I want the first item in a row to be at the leftmost place and the last item in a row to be at the rightmost place.
The rest of the items should maintain equal distance between them.

How can I achieve this using Tailwind CSS? Normally with some conditions, I know how to do it, but is there any way to do it directly with Tailwind?

**JSON response from API:**

```js
     const ourPartners = [
        {
            id: "partner01",
            pic: partner_01
        },
        {
            id: "partner02",
            pic: partner_02,
        },
        {
            id: "partner03",
            pic: partner_03,
        },
        {
            id: "partner04",
            pic: partner_04,
        },
        {
            id: "partner05",
            pic: partner_05,
        },
        {
            id: "partner06",
            pic: partner_06,
        },
        {
            id: "partner07",
            pic: partner_07,
        },
        {
            id: "partner08",
            pic: partner_08,
        }
    ]
```

**The code where I'm mapping over the array:**

```
      <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-between items-center">
          {
              ourPartners.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                      <div className={`md:w-1/4 w-1/2 mb-10 ${(index % 4 !== 0 ? ('flex justify-center') : ('flex justify-start'))}`} key={item.id}>
                          <div className="w-32 object-contain">
                              <Image
                                  alt="partner"
                                  width="auto"
                                  height="auto"
                                  src={item.pic}
                                  quality={100}
                              />
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  )
              })
          }
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @jme11 yes with tailwind it is little tricky . I also did same but i used function that takes index and return the required class for the particular item. I liked your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

I actually learned something new here too.  You can use nth-child now with Tailwind.

```
const Partners = () => {
  return (
    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2 gap-y-10 justify-between">
      {ourPartners.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={item.id}
            className="odd:justify-self-start even:justify-self-end md:[&:nth-child(4n+2)]:justify-self-center md:[&:nth-child(4n+3)]:justify-self-center"
          >
            <div className="w-32">
              <img alt="partner" width="auto" height="auto" src={item.pic} />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Partners;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but if I use gap then I have to provide different gap values for multiple breakpoints in order to maintain the same view